# Laravel 5.4 Cashier - bridging the gap in documentation

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I've been working my way through the documentation on Laravels website regarding Cashier. From the sounds of it, it seems like it is exactly what I need. A basic subscription configuration that integrates with Stripe. I am able to follow along fairly easily through the configuration section. Then it switches gears and talks about BrainTree integration for a bit. And then it hops right into creating subscriptions, citing the following code:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($stripeToken);
```

So my first question is - where is "$stripeToken" coming from? I feel like there's a fairly large gap in explanations here. Even when I run the code, it errors out saying $stripeToken could not be found.

Where am I setting/getting the $stripeToken from?

I have attempted to follow other video tutorials on setting up Cashier with Laravel, but these all seem to be outdated, as many of the steps to set it up are no longer relevant in Laravel 5.4. For example:

In the one tutorial, it says that you can check to see if a user is already subscribed to a plan in Stripe via the following:

```
$user->subscribed('main')
```

And in the video series, it shows him changing a database field (stripe_active) from 0 to 1, to show a different message in the view. With the new process however, there is no "stripe_active" field even created anymore.

So - at the risk of this being an open-ended vague question, I pose 3 questions to kick things off.

a.) Can anybody tell me how/where I set $stripeToken for the code in the documentation to work?

b.) Can anybody tell me how I can check to see if a subscription exists within Stripe using Cashier 7.0 & Laravel 5.4?

c.) Does anybody know of any good tutorials/videos that walk through this process using the latest versions of each?

Answer (score 2):

You're right-- there's a huge gap in the docs.

A) you need to create a form on the front end view, and generate the token yourself, which you capture via javascript and then submit via `POST`. It's easiest to do this with [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial), but it's more customizable with [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements).

B) you can see if a `User` has a subscription in Laravel using the built in methods described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing#checking-subscription-status. If you're asking about how to grab Stripe subscriptions by calling Stripe *from* Laravel, it appears you can do this using `$plans = Plan::getStripePlans();` from the `stripe/stripe-php` library which is a dependency of Laravel Cashier.

C) I found this tutorial to be very helpful, and at the moment it's up to date, though that may change: http://www.qcode.in/subscription-with-coupon-using-laravel-cashier-stripe/